How to use external HTML login form in Spring Authorization Server
I have mounted a Spring Authorization Server. All run right and I can login using the login page.

My question is that I don't use the login page proporcioned by Authorization Server, I have a frontend with HTML login form. Can I link my frontend HTML login form to use Authorization Server?

My stack:

Spring Authorization Server
Spring Resource
Spring Oauth client.
Java 21
Spring boot 3.1

Regards.

Can you post your configuration class where you define the SecurityFilterChain?

I haven't implemented any configuration class to customize Security Filter Chain yet...

Define the login page url in a SecurityFilterChain bean:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage("/login"));
        return http.build();
    }
}

